# Proguard Note for unknown class 'Object' with Android Studio and Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, proguard

I've created a new project in Android Studio and am using Gradle to build it.

I've added my Proguard integration for release builds, and I am seeing this Note every time I run my `assembleRelease` step:

```
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'Object'
      Maybe you meant the fully qualified name 'java.lang.Object'?
```

None of my Proguard configuration files, or the ones in the Android SDK folder include an unqualified name `Object`.

My `build.gradle` includes:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')

        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

I even see the same Note when I remove both the `proguardFile` lines above, and also if I delete my custom Proguard rules (each time doing a clean before rebuilding).

I'm guessing this is a benign issue with the Proguard plugin for Gradle?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion Eric Lafortune!  Adding `-printconfiguration` to my proguard.txt revealed that the problem was in the google-play-services_lib (r13).

The guilty Proguard rule is (it should be `java.lang.Object[][]`):

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}
```

You can see this on a Mac by right clicking on `Android Studio`, do `Show Package Contents`, then browse to `sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/proguard.txt`.

The quickest workaround is to add the correct Proguard rule into your own Proguard configuration and just ignore the Proguard Note.

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected java.lang.Object[][] getContents();
}
```

I raised this bug with Google as [Android Issue #63095](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63095).

Comment: I have added the rule but it is still complaining. I guess this happens because the old rule is still hanging in the config file after my own rule. Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of any unqualified references to `Object` in the Android SDK, but you could specify the option `-printconfiguration config.txt` to write out the complete configuration and look for the reference. It could be a method argument or a return value, which is easy to overlook.

Comment: Where/how do we specify this option? As part of what command?? And against which txt file???

Comment: I tried adding `-printconfiguration config.txt` to one of the proguard rules files in my project but when building my app I get this error message: `Flag -printconfiguration config.txt is not supported by the built-in shrinker.`

Comment: you can use -printconfiguration in your proguard-rules.pro, to see logs in Build